# Why do I keep getting errors with NodeJs and npm when installing yeoman?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, yeoman, git-bash

I am currently on windows 7 trying to install nodejs and npm to use with git and yeoman. I have uninstalled node and git multiple times and keep getting the same errors

```
`Welcome to Git (version 1.9.4-preview20140815)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

Jeff@JEFF-PC ~
$ node --version
v0.10.32

Jeff@JEFF-PC ~
$ npm --version
1.4.28

Jeff@JEFF-PC ~
$ npm install --global yo
c:\UsersJeffnpm\yo -> c:\UsersJeffnpm\node_modules\yo\cli.js

> yo@1.2.1 postinstall c:\UsersJeffnpm\node_modules\yo
> node ./scripts/doctor

[Yeoman Doctor] Uh oh, I found potential errors on your machine
---------------

[Error] npm root value is not in your NODE_PATH
  [info]
    NODE_PATH = :\Users\Jeff\npm\node_modules:\home\npm\lib\node_modules
    npm root  = c:\UsersJeffnpm\node_modules

  [Fix] Append the npm root value to your NODE_PATH variable
    If you're using cmd.exe, run this command to fix the issue:
      setx NODE_PATH "%NODE_PATH%;c:\UsersJeffnpm\node_modules"
    Then restart your command line. Otherwise, you can setup NODE_PATH manually:

      https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/set-environment-variabl
es.md#windows
```

I've tried the command that the yeoman doctor suggested and tried editing the environment variables manually and keep getting these errors. Do I need to edit my .bashrc or .gitconfig files?

Here's my .bashrc content:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
 export NODE_PATH=:/Users/Jeff/npm/node_modules
 export NODE_PATH=:/Users/Jeff/npm/node_modules:/home//npm/lib/node_modules
```

If I can change my environment variables or edit my paths please let me know! I greatly appreciate any help you have!

Answer (score 0):

In the second line of your `.bashrc` you'll note that you have `/home//npm/lib/node_modules`. Based off the other items in that file I'm betting it should be `/Users/Jeff/npm/lib/node_modules` or similar.